# Java in Chrome 34

Tags: java, google-chrome

I have installed the old version of chrome (34) because it is supposed to be able to work with java (as others have reported.) my question is, how do i get java to work in chrome 34? I have tried to follow java instructions but it still says my plugin is lower than 1.6 (anyone who has to use marvin sketch might understand, organic chemistry is pain). Could anyone help me with a walkthrough of setting this up? Or even how to start over from basically installing java?  thanks

Comment: check your browser plugin. type `chrome://plugins` in address bar and active or update

Comment: I typed that in, there is no java plugin at all? i know i have it in the plugins folder of opt/google/chrome/plugins

Comment: but chrome doesn't use any java plugin with itself!

Comment: after installing `java 1.7` run `cd /opt/google/chrome && sudo ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so`. if your java installation is 64bit, replace **i386** with **amd64**

Comment: for more read http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Oracle-Java-in-Your-Web-Browsers-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: yes yes i figured this out now, i ws lookig at the code, i realized it was giving me instructions for 64 bit, and somehow i didnt have a java folder so i just linked '/usr/local/jre1.7.0_67/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so' in the plugins folder i made earlier. thank you!

Comment: [If this work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525279/java-in-chrome-34?noredirect=1#comment715388_525279) for you, I write that as an answer? Your welcome.

Comment: yes that worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [installing java 1.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) run below command to make a symbolic link

```
cd /opt/google/chrome
sudo ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_40/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

This will create a symbolic link from the Java JRE(Java Runtime Environment) plugin `libnpjp2.so` to your Google Chrome web browser

Note: if your java installation is **64bit**, replace **i386** with **amd64** in above command.

[source](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Oracle-Java-in-Your-Web-Browsers-on-Ubuntu-Linux)